# Decomposition of a matrix into multiplication of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the *necessary* condition for a real, dense matrix $A_{m\times n}$ to be written as $$B_{m×c}C_{c×k}D_{k×n}$$ where $c,k\ll m,n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think of this in terms of linear maps - we have a linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and want to know when it factors as

$$ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb R ^k \to \mathbb R^c \to \mathbb R^m.$$

A linear map cannot increase dimension, so a necessary condition for this factorization is that $\operatorname{rank} A \le \min(c,k)$; otherwise one of the inner maps would lose too much dimension. In fact, this is necessary *and* sufficient - this is essentially the [Rank factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).